# Retrieve the original (parent) post id from a comment via the notifications table

Tags: facebook-fql

I have been looking high and low for this answer reading the FQL API, searching the interwebs and I cannot find the answer to this question.

I am querying the notifications table to identify when someone comments on a post that the user has made. I'm trying to then query that original post to create a thread of the conversation in the app. But I cannot figure out how to get the ID of the the original (parent) post. I've tried the stream table, the comments table, but nothing that I can find will return to the me id of the original post that this comment is in reply to.

This has to be possible (and obvious). I just need to get the ID of original post that the comment is from.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Isn’t it simply the `object_id` that you are looking for …? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/notification

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but isn't the object_id in the notifications the id of the comment, not the original post?

Comment: I tried it with the Graph API Explorer, and the object_id seems to link to the object that some commented (or did something else) on.

Comment: Hmm. Sorry, maybe I'm not getting it. Here is an example of me posting on my wife's wall. She commented back. The notification table returns the object_id of her comment, not my original post on her wall. If I put that object_id into a query of the comments table I see her comment. If I put it in the stream table to retrieve the original post, I get nothing. Here is the query: SELECT message, actor_id FROM stream WHERE post_id = $object_id

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I wasn't using the full object id. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Can you post the answer you are actually using?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have a comment id in format `XXXXXXXX_YYYYY`

FQL is an easiest way to get post ID

```
SELECT parent_id,post_id  FROM comment WHERE id = 'XXXXXXXX_YYYYY'
```

For Graph API is a bit tricky because facebook doesn't provide post id information for you.
However the `XXXXXXXX` in your comment id `XXXXXXXX_YYYYY` is object id for your post.
Assume your page id is `ZZZZZZZZ`. If you want to know the post id of comment id `XXXXXXXX_YYYYY`.

Post id for graph is `ZZZZZZZZ_XXXXXXXX` ( [PAGE ID]_[POST ID] )

**BUT:** some comment id come from post that created by album not follow this method. I will be more complicate because 1 album post contain a lot of photo posts and facebook not return the correct post id when you query it.
e.g. your comment on photo is `1234_5678` your page id is `5555`. When you use FQL above it will return post_id = `5555_1234` but when you use this id to search for a post it will return

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request.",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

Because `1234` is just object_id of this post not the post_id. You need to use `1234` as object_id to search for post_id later.